# Xcode keeps throwing that i should disable bitcode even though i already disabled it

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm working on react native project and i already deployed android to store without any problem  so this time i'm trying to build iOS version but Xcode keeps throwing below error

```
d: '/Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[project]-coivpexlwowderaljfvolsjfftjk/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Permission-Camera/libPermission-Camera.a(Permission-Camera-dummy.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[project]-coivpexlwowderaljfvolsjfftjk/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Permission-Camera/libPermission-Camera.a' for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But as i said i already disabled it for all pods. Since i'm using `use_frameworks!` i added below patch in my podfile.

```rb
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
  end
end
```

Also the weird thing is that i'm not only getting this error.. Sometimes it throws another error

```
Link react_native_geolocation_service
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTEventEMITTER
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTEventEMITTER
Undefined symbol: _RCTRegisterModule
```

So both of the above errors is showing randomly..
And i can build it for simulator it only happens when i build it for real devices or archiving.

Here is my environment

#### podfile

```rb
platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

# Convert all permission pods into static libraries
pre_install do |installer|
  Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-')
      def pod.build_type;
        # Uncomment the line corresponding to your CocoaPods version
        Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
        # Pod::Target::BuildType.static_library # < 1.9
      end
    end
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  # Patch for issue using use_frameworks with hermes
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
  react_native_post_install(installer)
  __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
end

# firebase settings
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

target 'amorNative' do
  # To resolve ios build error: it keeps getting error even commenting out use_flipper!()
  config = use_native_modules!

  # firebase settings
  use_frameworks!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
#     :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  # React Native Permissions
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary"
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAccuracy', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAccuracy"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"

  target 'amorNativeTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
#   use_flipper!()
end
```

#### react-native info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8257U CPU @ 1.40GHz
    Memory: 176.47 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.17.1 - /usr/local/opt/node@16/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.15.0 - /usr/local/opt/node@16/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.10.03.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.5, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.2 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683
    Xcode: 13.4.1/13F100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.15 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0
    react-native: 0.69.1 => 0.69.1
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

#### package.json

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "appcenter": "^4.4.5",
    "appcenter-analytics": "^4.4.5",
    "appcenter-crashes": "^4.4.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "js-base64": "^3.7.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.4",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.1",
    "react-native-camera-kit": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.5",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.6",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-encrypted-storage": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.15.0",
    "react-native-share": "^7.9.0",
    "react-native-simple-dialogs": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.22.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "url-parse": "^1.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.67.3",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/url-parse": "^1.4.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.17.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
```

Comment: Random is bad, as a reproduction, that means you're not even reproducing it yourself so others will certainly have poor results. Try react-native-clean-project in between builds. Also check my rnfbdemo repo and the make-demo script, it has a couple other workarounds, particular about which architectures to exclude -maybe helps with simulator vs real device issue. Other than that, unsure, this is not really a reproduction. My make-demo is executable and works every time, maybe try it

Comment: Hi @MikeHardy. Thank you for your comment! i agree that i should be able to reproduce it if i want to ask someone help so i made a sample repo which can produce the same error. I'll really appreciate if you can check it out.

This is the sample repo: https://github.com/Y-k-Y/Sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found what the problem was. there is bitcode option for each pods and also for the target as well and i didn't disable the target's bitcode option. After i disabled, the error was gone.

I hope it can help someone like me.
[image]